# Duda sobre el uso del polimorfismo

Tags: java, polimorfismo

Suponiendo que tengo una clase vehículo del tipo:

```
public class Vehiculo {
    protected String matricula;
    protected String marca;
    protected String modelo;

    public Vehiculo(String matricula, String marca, String modelo) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
}
```

Y otra clase que hereda de la anterior:

```
public class Coche extends Vehiculo {
    private int puertas;

    public Coche(int puertas, String marca, String modelo, String color) {
        super(marca, modelo, color);
        this.puertas = puertas;
    }
}
```

Y por último mi clase main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehiculo misVehiculos[] = new Vehiculo[3];

        Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo("4425FZG", "Citroen", "Saxo");
        Vehiculo v2 = new Coche(4, "2525HHH", "Peugeot", "206");
        Coche c1 = new Coche(4, "4545RGX", "Citroen", "Xsara");

        misVehiculos[0] = v1;
        misVehiculos[1] = v2;
        misVehiculos[2] = c1;
    }

}
```

No veo la diferencia entre crear un objeto tipo “Coche c1 = new Coche()” a crearlo como “Vehiculo v1 = new Coche()”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La verdad no se si tu ejemplo califica para mostrar polimorfismo.

Algo más claro sería:

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {
  public abstract void ponerEnMovimiento(); 
}

public class AutoComun extends Vehiculo {
  @Override
  public void ponerEnMovimiento(){
    moverPalancaManualAPrimera();
  }

  private void moverPalancaManualAPrimera() {
    ...
  }
}

public class AutoAutomatico extends Vehiculo {
  @Override
  public void ponerEnMovimiento(){
    ponerPalancaEnDrive();
  }

  private void ponerPalancaEnDrive() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Luego en un programa podes tener:

```
Vehiculo vehiculo = null;
Random random = new Random();
if(random.nexInt(10) > 5) {
  vehiculo = new AutoAutomatico();
} else { 
  vehiculo = new AutoComun();
}
vehiculo.ponerEnMovimiento();
```

donde la variable de la superclase puede almacenar indistintamente una referencia a cualquiera de sus dos clases heredadas.

Usando `Random` de esta forma para el ejemplo, 50% de las veces será un objeto de `AutoAutomatico` y 50% será un objeto de `AutoComun`.

Cuando se llama el método `ponerEnMovimiento()` se ejecutará la implementación del método acorde al objeto que se haya instanciado.

Nota: Esto se podría haberse hecho con una interface en lugar de una superclase, pero para el ejemplo, me parece que hacerlo de esta manera es más simple de entender.

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia es mínima pero significativa.

En el caso de `Coche c1 = new Coche()` a través de la variable `c1` puedes acceder a todos los miembros públicos del objeto de tipo `Coche` al que hace referencia.

Por otro lado si lo haces así `Vehiculo v1 = new Coche()` a través de la variable `v1` solo puedes tener acceso a los miembros públicos de la clase `Vehiculo` a pesar que la variable sigue haciendo referencia a un objeto de tipo `Coche`.

Agrego algunas cosas a tus clases para que entiendas mejor de lo que hablo.

```
public class Vehiculo {
    protected String matricula;
    protected String marca;
    protected String modelo;

    public void encenderMotor() {
        // lógica del método
    }
}

public class Coche extends Vehiculo {
    private int puertas;

    public bloquearPuertas() {
        // lógica del método
    }
}


public class Bote extends Vehiculo {
    public echarAncla() {
        // lógica del método
    }
}
```

Teniendo la jerarquía de clases anteriores lo siguiente sería completamente válido

```
Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo();
Coche c1 = new Coche();
Bote b1 = new Bote();

v1.encenderMotor();
c1.bloquearPuertas();
b1.echarAncla();
```

Pero si declaramos las variables del siguiente modo no podríamos hacer lo mismo

```
Vehiculo c1 = new Coche();
Vehiculo b1 = new Bote();

c1.bloquearPuertas(); // error de compilación
b1.echarAncla();      // error de compilación
```

Aunque parezca que no tiene sentido declarar la variable del tipo del padre, esto es muy útil cuando tenemos una jerarquía de clases y cada clase más específica sobrescribe la implementación de un (o varios) método del padre. En este escenario podríamos tener lo siguiente:

```
public class Vehiculo {
    public void acelerar() {
        System.out.println("Acelera vehiculo");
    }
}

public class Coche extends Vehiculo {
    public void acelerar() {
        System.out.println("Acelera coche");
    }
}


public class Bote extends Vehiculo {
    public void acelerar() {
        System.out.println("Acelera bote");
    }
}

Vehiculo[] arr = {new Vehiculo(), new Coche(), new Bote()};

arr[0].acelerar();
arr[1].acelerar();
arr[2].acelerar();
```

Y la salida sería esta

```
Acelera vehiculo
Acelera coche
Acelera bote
```

Puesto que aunque el tipo de dato del arreglo sea `Vehiculo` lo que se almacena en cada posición es un objeto del tipo correspondiente por lo que se ejecuta el método de la clase más específica (la real del objeto).

Comment: Pero entonces, cuando declaras la variable del tipo del padre, como por ejemplo Vehiculo c1 = new Coche(), no se puede hacer uso de los métodos específicos de la clase Coche. Solo tiene sentido hacer este tipo de declaración para sobrescribir métodos de la superclase ¿cierto? Porque en este caso no se puede hacer uso del método bloquearPuertas().

Comment: Este tipo de técnicas se llaman abstracción y permiten desacoplar el código de implementaciones concretas, lo que es muy útil cuando necesitamos preocuparnos por la escalabilidad de los sistemas. Si estás comenzando con la programación te recomiendo no preocuparte ahora mismo de esto, solo te lo pongo para comentarte para que sirven este tipo de técnicas en el mundo real. De todos modos siempre vas a poder obtener un referencia al tipo de objeto real haciendo uso de `instanceof` y de `castings`. Estudia sobre esto que si está muy ligado al polimorfismo.